Fitting circles on each end of a prolong region on binary masks to find a path for extrusion
I work on a program to find path for an extruder to fill prolonged regions, represented as white regions on 2D binary masks (mask size 1280x720 px). On a mask, there is always a single region. The length is always greater that the width. The width of the regions varies but generally corresponds approximately to the width of the extruder (extrusion width can be adjusted).
Currently, I find the path using A* (library pathfinding) with modified binary masks (in a way that following the centerline gives a "cheapest" path).
But I have difficulties with finding start and end points for the path generation. I was thinking to try to fit the circles at the end of each region. Then use their centerpoints as start and end nodes for pathfinding algorithm. Do you have an idea how such fitting of two circles one on each end can be implemented? As a reference, here is a picture I draw to illustrate what I am trying to achieve (ps I am a bad drawer)enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

...What? I'm intrigued, but I'm also confused. Is this something akin to a 3D printer? Do the multiple masks shown in your drawing relate meaningfully to each other, or are they all independent examples? Would it be possible to share a [mre] that is perhaps simplified of unrelated complexities but demonstrates what you're talking about?

@CrazyChucky Yes, it is a kind of a 3D printer. More precise, this is for a machine that should extrude a sort of "worms" or "sausages" following the given 2D masks.  The multiple masks shown on the drawing are not somehow related to each other, they just represent independent cases how the masks can look like.
